# Acessar elemento de lista dentro de lista em Python

Tags: python, lista

Tenho duas listas dentro de uma lista e cada índice da lista contém um par ordenado, desta forma:

```
[[2, 5], [3, 6], ..., [x, f(x)]]
```

Quero saber como acessar um item específico de uma das listas, pois queria acessar apenas o valor **x** do exemplo que mostrei. Algo como `index.lista[x]` em um determinado índice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em Python lista é uma coleção mutável e ordenada cujo o acesso dos elementos são feito através de um índice, índice cujo a numeração começa do zero.

Sabendo disso e que uma lista aninha nada mais é que uma lista dentro de outra lista, para acessar listas aninhada basta acessar o elemento desejado usando dois índices. O primeiro índice para obter a sub-lista e segundo índice para obter o item requisitado.

```
#Define a função f(x)
def f(x):
  return x + 3

#Constroi a lista de pares ordenados [x,f(x)]
lista = [[x,f(x)] for x in range(2,10)]

#Imprime o x para o terceiro par ordenado
print(f'x = {lista[2][0]}')

#Imprime o f(x) para o terceiro par ordenado
print(f'f(x) = {lista[2][1]}')
```

Código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/TerribleDroopyShareware

Comment: Affz, foi mais rápido do que eu kkk Quando eu já estava quase acabando de responder apareceu que você já tinha respondido.

Comment: Deu certo aqui, vlw!

Answer (score 2):

Da mesma forma que você acessa um elemento dentro de uma unidimensional, você também acessa em lista multidimensional. Para acessar um item dentro de uma lista, você escreveria o seguinte código:

```
lista[indice]
```

Ao fazer isso, você obtém o item que está na posição que você especificou. No caso de listas multidimensionais, os valores dentro delas seriam outras listas, sendo assim, você obteria uma outra lista e com isso poderia fazer o mesmo processo para acessar o item. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
lista1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]                                               # Unidimensional
lista2 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]                                       # Bidimensional
lista3 = [[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]], [["macarrão", "pizza", "salada"]]]  # Tridimensional

# Abaixo eu obtenho o valor 3 de todas as listas
#--------------------------------------------------

# Obtém o valor na posição 2 
lista1[2] 

# Obtém a lista "[3,4]" na posição 1 e depois obtém o valor na posição 0 dessa lista
lista2[1][0] 

# Obtém a lista "[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]" na posição 0 e realiza as mesmas etapas acima
lista3[0][1][0]
```

Assim como o Augusto Varques falou, você pode criar uma lista de pares ordenados utilizando compreensão de lista, mas eu acho que essa sintaxe ainda é um pouco difícil para você. Então vamos descomplicar isso.

```
#Define a função f(x)
def f(x):
  return x + 3

#Constroi a lista de pares ordenados [x,f(x)]
lista = [[x,f(x)] for x in range(2,10)]
```

No código acima que o Augusto fez, o *for loop* percorre os valores obtidos pelo `range` passando-os para a variável **x**. Depois disso, esse valor é passado dentro da lista `[x, f(x)]` na primeiro posição e é usado como argumento para a função `f()` para retornar o seu valor somado a `3`. Por fim, a cada volta do laço `for`, uma lista é retornada para dentro da lista "principal".

Ficou difícil ainda assim ? Então veja o código abaixo que faz a mesma coisa do código acima só que de uma forma menos compacta só que mais fácil de entender:

```
def criaPares(start = 2, end = 5):
    lista = []

    for x in range(start, end):
        lista.append( [x, x + 3 ] )
    return lista
```

Comment: Foi o meu último voto do dia https://imgur.com/a/tb6VtSb

Comment: @AugustoVasques kkkk cheguei na hora então xD

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que você está querendo algo que receba x e retorne o índice na lista, mas como x está dentro de outra lista precisa de uma função:

```
def procura_lista(l, x):
    for posicao, valor in enumerate(l):
        if valor[0] == x:
            return posicao
    raise Exception("Nao encontrado")
```

Esta função recebe a lista e o valor que você deseja procurar na primeira posição da sub-lista. Ela retorna a posição onde foi encontrado e gera uma exceção caso não tenha sido encontrado. Na função, enumerate foi usada para criar um par posicao, valor, onde posicao é o índice do valor em questão.

Por exemplo:

```
>>> vv = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [6, 7]]
>>> procura_lista(vv, 1)
0
>>> procura_lista(vv, 3)
1
>>> procura_lista(vv, 6)
2
>>> print(vv[procura_lista(vv, 1)])
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você deseja implementar um script que seja capaz de exibir **apenas** o **1º** do par ordenado contido em cada **sublistas** de uma determinada **lista**.

Pois bem, para implementar um código que seja capaz de realizar tal tarefa, deves ter consciência que deves iterar sobre a lista **mais externa** e, também, sobra as **listas mais internas** - as sublistas.

Para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
lista = [[2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7], [5, 8]]

for lis in lista:
    for c in lis:
        if c == lis[0]:
            print(c)
```

Observe que quando executamos o seguinte código o **1º for** começará à iterar sobre a lista mais externa, ou seja, sobre a lista denominada de `lista`. Prosseguindo a execução, o **2º for** começará a iterar sobre **cada uma** das listas internas - sublistas - e, com a ajuda do bloco **if** será verificado se o valor da respectiva iteração pertence ao primeiro elemento do par ordenado - primeiro elemento da sublista, ou seja, elemento correspondente à posição `lis[0]`. Caso positivo, o mesmo é exibido na tela.

Observe que os resultados deste código será exibido em uma coluna.

Agora se deseja exibir estes valores na mesma linha, basta utilizar o seguinte código:

```
lista = [[2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7], [5, 8]]

for lis in lista:
    for c in lis:
        if c == lis[0]:
            print(c, end=' ')
print()
```

Observe que estes dois códigos é capaz de trabalhar com apenas um lista, que é justamente a lista que escrevi dentro do código.

Agora imagine a seguinte situação: **"Monte uma lista formada por **6** sublistas, onde cada uma delas contenha um par ordenado - (x, f(x)) - onde `"x"` seja um valor inteiro e `"f(x)"` seja o quadrado de `"x"`**.

**Como poderíamos resolver esta situação?**

Para resolver esta situação devemos:

1. Inserir cada um dos `6` valores - um por vez;
2. Montar a lista contendo as `6` sublistas, cada uma com seu respectivo par ordenado;
3. Exibir a lista;
4. Capturar apenas as componentes "x" de cada par ordenado e exibi-los.

Seguindo esta lógica podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
# Primeiro bloco for:
lista = list()
for i in range(1, 7):
    par_ordenado = list()
    for j in range(1, 3):
        if j == 1:
            par_ordenado.append(int(input(f'Digite o valor do {i}º "X": ')))
        else:
            par_ordenado.append(par_ordenado[0] ** 2)
    lista.append(par_ordenado)
print(f'A lista montada é:\n{lista}')

# Segundo bloco for:
print('As componentes "x" do pares ordenados são:')
for lis in lista:
    for c in lis:
        if c == lis[0]:
            print(c, end=' ')
print()
```

**Observação**

Se você deseja exibir as componentes "f(x)" do para ordenado, basta você ir no **2º bloco for** e substituir a linha de comando...

```
if c == lis[0]
```

por...

```
if c == lis[1]
```